# Do all air vehicles have the same height limit?

Tags: just-cause-3

Do all planes/helicopters have the same flight height limit? Or are there differences between different planes/helicopters?

There is [an](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=25825237#25825237) [ongoing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=25825846#25825846) [fight](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=25826660#25826660) [for](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=25849423#25849423) [a highscore](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=25870195#25870195) (in flinging people as far away as possible). So I need to find the place where I can get an enemy as high as possible before I fling him away.

Does it matter what plane/heli I attach my enemy too? I know I flew up last night with a heli to the height limit (for that heli anyway), but then botched my foe-flinging.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the same for all, but I recommend a jet plane because while flinging a person it will give them more speed than a helicopter. Good luck!